# Upload files PWA, open directly the files system

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I'm building PWA React App. The problem is that when I use `input` with `type='file'`, the android phone opens a window for the user to choose between camera or file system

```
 <input
     id="upload-photo"
     name="upload-photo"
     type="file"
     accept="image/*"
/>
```

I would like to open directly the file system and to avoid user choose from where to import the file

I had tried `window.showOpenFilePicker()`, but gives me an error that window.showOpenFilePicker() is not a function, even in HTTPS

Comment: https://caniuse.com/?search=showOpenFilePicker   Unfortunately there is no reliable way to do this, you could try removing the `accept` attribute and this should give you the files, but of course the user could then select none image files too..

Comment: Unfortunately, even if remove the accept attribute prompt me to choose between camera and gallery.